# Write RDD[OmnitureData] to S3

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, rdd

I have a RDD that contains objects type of my custom class OmnitureData. OmnitureData data contains 1000's of data variable. I want to write the data to S3.

```
data: RDD[OmnitureData]
data.saveAsTextFile(path)
```

In S3 I am seeing data as:

```
OmnitureFeedOutputEntry@5655c68b
OmnitureFeedOutputEntry@kgfwe77c
OmnitureFeedOutputEntry@4rjkks8f
OmnitureFeedOutputEntry@57bfgk6d
OmnitureFeedOutputEntry@646lk6sd
```

How can I store it in a way that I can see the actual data of OmnitureData members?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

```
def writeOnS3(data: RDD[OmnitureFeedOutputEntry], path: String)= {
try {
  val finalData: RDD[String] = data.map(x => {
    implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)
    write(x)})
  finalData.saveAsTextFile(path)
  logger.info("task=writeOnS3, status=success")
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>  logger.error("task=writeOnS3, status=failure")
}
```

}